# how to output success or failure of cp command to file

Tags: output, cp, logfile

I'm going to be running a shell script containing a CP command using a scheduled cron job.  I would like to include in the script something to output to a log file whether the copy was successful or failed.

Appreciate any advice in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 33):

You can check the return code of cp. From the cp man page:

```
EXIT STATUS
    The cp utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.
```

The exit code of the last operation is stored in the special variable $?, so you can do something like this:

```
cp .. ..
echo $? >> outputfile
```

Most likely, you'll want to have some sort of "custom" error message. For that purpose, you can check the value of $?

```
cp .. ..
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "there was an error" >> outputfile
fi
```

I hope that gets you started.

Comment: When I try this the output I get is..-bash: 0: command not found

Comment: That works. Thank you. If i wanted a customized message something other than 0 written to the log file what would I need to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, instead of just printing the exit code to the file, check it first with if.

Comment: sorry I'm really new to this.  Would that be something like if [$? -eq 0]; echo 'copied success' >> my_file.txt.  I get a syntax error: unexpected end of file from this.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. rm -rf ../feeds/SetupID_162/TODAY/TODAY/* if [ $? -ne 0 ] then echo "copied success" >> my_file fi  I get the error Macquarie.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
Macquarie.sh: line 5: `fi'

Comment: Post your entire file on pastebin or something similar. (rep too low for chat, so abusing the comments for once).